# How to open a file using the path of a file, once the site is published?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2012

```
 public ActionResult OpenFile(string path)
    {
        Process.Start(@"" + path);
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

I have this piece of code that works very well locally, but once the site published this feature no longer works. Yet the web request says it's ok.

[image]

I am using ASP.Net Framework and Windows Server 2012

Comment: I'm fairly certain the `@"" + path` is pointless. Just do `Process.Start(path);`

Comment: I tried it still does not work

Comment: My *comment* isn't an answer, it's a suggestion towards your code. Having `@"" + string` isn't going to change anything about the `string`. Just adds unnecessary code. Also- please add as much information about your issue that you can. Elaborate on "No longer works". Are you getting errors? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: Try wrapping your logic in a try catch to see what exception you get (if any) I suspect that Process.Start will only work within the context of a Windows Process. If your file is on a remote web server you will need to perform a web request for it. Could you not perform a GET on the document and parse the JSON in the response?

Comment: No, there is no error displayed otherwise I wanted to share it. It does not matter if you do not have an answer to everything.

Comment: What value are you supplying for `path` when you try this? And why do you want to use Process.Start - what are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to make it execute an arbitrary program on the server (that sounds like a terrible security vulnerability, to me...)? Or are you trying to make it download a document from the server or something? It's a bit unclear what the purpose of the code is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because on the server, the application doesn't have permissions to access the `path`, whereas locally it does.

You should probably make sure that the file at `path` is accessible by the application, and if it isn't, choose a better location like:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

You could also mess around with the folder permissions to allow the application to access the `path` but I don't recommend this because it's not portable.

Comment: But of course, I am taking a guess here because you haven't provided very much information other than saying it "no longer works."